# Ошибка сборки двух классов при указании import друг на друга

Tags: objective-c, xcode, компиляция

Не могу понять в чём дело, xcode 4.4 и новый проект одного окна. Создал два класса `Obj1` и `Obj2` использую один класс в другом.

Код  `Obj1`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MFObj2.h"

@interface MFObj1 : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) MFObj2 * o2;

@end
```

Код  `Obj2`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MFObj1.h"

@interface MFObj2 : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) MFObj1 * o1;

@end
```

При сборке проекта имею кучу ошибок, если один класс не использует другой, сборка проходит без проблем.

В чём может быть дело, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В интерфейсном модуле одного из классов ( например, во втором), вместо импорта надо написать:

[@class](/users/4572/classltd) MFObj1;

А импорт перенести в файл реализации MDObj2.m

Answer (score 0):

Можно конечно и как написал [@voldemarus](/users/3732/voldemarus) , но это не есть хорошо т.к. будут проблемы с памятью (подозреваю, что утечка с АРК и краш без оного). Лучше используйте делегирование или как минимум не делайте их оба retain, сделайте один assign

Comment: Дело в том, что @property здесь в качестве примера, если будет метод с указанием типа переменной Obj1 в классе Obj2 то ситуация с ошибкой будет аналогичная. Сейчас проблема решена, до этого обошел её используя id, но это не удобно.

Comment: А зачем вам нужны такие перекресные ссылки? Может стоит нужные части в отдельный класс вынести? В общем, не видя причин и не понимая что вы хотите получить что-то советовать сложно, но такая ситуация явно указывает на просчет в архитектуре приложения

Comment: Не будет ни краша ни утечек памяти. Это стандартное решение, описанное в руководстве по Objective-C.

Comment: А если так obj1.obj2=obj2; obj2.obj1=obj1; ? Я действительно не знаю что получится когда это все освобождать, компа с маком под рукой нет.